# How do I update Xubuntu 11.10 to Xubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Tags: upgrade

I am currently using Xubuntu 11.10 and want to migrate to 12.04 LTS (Xubuntu version) as the support is ending in April.

The upgrade option is only showing Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.
How can I upgrade my current OS to the required version?

Comment: LiveCD? Back-up your files, first. Back-up the `/home` directory.

Comment: Look at this question: [How do I upgrade from 10.04 or 11.10 to 12.04?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-from-10-04-or-11-10-to-12-04) - this question specifically answers about Ubuntu. But Xubuntu shouldn't be much different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have Xubuntu installed, the upgrade to Ubuntu 12.04 option will upgrade to Xubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Tested automatically got updated to 12.04 xbuntu ;)